# How do I format a multi-line TODO comment in PyCharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, comments, multiline, todo

I want to add a multi-line TODO comment to my PyCharm project.

```
# TODO: Multiple errors can be wrapped inside an exception.
#       WfcApiException should do recursive error checking to locate
#       and store an arbitrary number of nested errors.
```

Unfortunately, PyCharm only recognizes the first line as a TODO comment. Any following lines are viewed as standard Python comments.

[image: Failed attempt at a multi-line TODO statement in PyCharm]

What is the correct way to format a multi-line TODO comment in PyCharm?

Comment: Unfortunately, you cannot format multiline TODO comments using PyCharm. There are numerous forum posts that you can google up to confirm this.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Pycharm 2018.3 does support multiline todo, yay!

https://youtu.be/5gJ7_3wCfUk?t=65

https://blog.jetbrains.com/pycharm/2018/11/pycharm-2018-3-out-now/

So, using your TODO comment:

```
# TODO: Multiple errors can be wrapped inside an exception.
#       WfcApiException should do recursive error checking to locate
#       and store an arbitrary number of nested errors.
```

yields:

[image]

Actually, you only need to indent the following lines one character to the right of the `TODO` so this would be just on the limit from being detected:

[image]

And the todo is captured as a single item, of course:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

**Update: It appears JetBrains added this feature, see payala's answer**

PyCharm [does not](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206590695-Multi-line-TODO-lists) support multi-line TODOs, one alternative option would be to use a multi line string

```
'''
TODO foobar
foobar
'''
```

This won't have the TODO highlighting like `# TODO foo`, but it will stand out from the rest of your code with the string highlighting.

You could also try

```
# TODO -----------------
# TODO  foobar this
# TODO  comment 
# TODO  comment
# TODO  comment
# TODO ------------------
```

If you have a particularly chunky and important TODO note.

Comment: In addition to this, you can easily accomplish the multi-line `# TODO` by double-pressing and holding `CTRL` key to enable multi-line cursor.  See documentation here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/multicursor.html
I cannot say this will look pretty but to accomplish what OP wants, this is one of the easiest way.